# How to calculate the P/E ratio of the stocks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Formula to calculate is,  `Portfolio P/E = Net Worth/Sum(Stock EPS * Shares Held)`

I have the value for net Worth but I am unable to iterate over the EPS values and multiply it by the shares held. Can you please suggest some solution for this. Thank you!
Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQ08MJxIJ0vDuK3G6Wms?p=preview)

```
        <div>
            <h3>P/E Ratio: {{getNetWorth())}}
        </div>
```

Script:

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
     $scope.stocksArray = [];
     var indexes = [];
     var epsindex = [];
     var eps = {};
     $scope.eps = response.data.eps;
```

Comment: Taking a look my friend

Comment: This looks like a simple fix. Make a new function `getPortfolioPE()`. Also when instansiating your stock objects, add stock EPS  as a field in that object, this will make it easier for you to access when iterating over the stock array.

Comment: Have tried but not sure exactly. Can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: I've had some fun with angular in the last few days, checkout this calculator I've made - http://btcprofitcalc.treyfoster.com/

Comment: This is really cool man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't win any awards, but [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oNfj75PJ9czUrA3JQo59?p=preview) is the long and short of the problem.

Your json file is structured oddly like this:

```
  -price
    --stock-name:stock-price
  -eps
    --stock-name:stock-eps
```

It should be structure like this:

```
  -stock-name
    --price:actual-price
    --eps:actual-eps
```

This would let you pull it in as objects without needing to instantiate the entire collection manually. But I played with the data I was given and it works.

The key is the following two line

```
$scope.eps = response.data.eps;
```

AND

```
mystock.eps = $scope.eps[key];
```

By adding the eps collection as a seperate array I was able to add it as a field in the object property.

`getPortfolioPE()` was the easy part:

```
$scope.getPortfolioPE = function(){
          let temp = 0;
          let total = 0;
          for(let i = 0; i < $scope.stocksArray.length; i++){
            total += $scope.stocksArray[i].eps * $scope.stocksArray[i].shares
          }
          temp += $scope.getNetWorth()/ total;
          return temp.toFixed(2);

        }
```

Comment: Hey thats cool. Thank you.It works. But why is it showing Portfolio P/E : NaN initially.

Comment: That's because there are no stocks initially. This means 0 in the divisor in `getPortfolioPE()` A simple fix to this is to add `if(total == 0){total = 1;}` before returning the result, which has no effect on the result should there be a stock.

Comment: Here that line has been added -https://plnkr.co/edit/oNfj75PJ9czUrA3JQo59?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think your $http.get should return an array of stocks, and the PE ratio is a property of each array element.

Therefore, you should have something like this in controller:

```
$scope.stocks = response.data;
```

And you may need use ng-repeat in template, something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in stocks">
    You PE is: {{item.pe}}
</li>
```